# IBM RAD 8.5 installation failed

Tags: installation, failed-installation, ibm-rad

I'm dealing with an ugly error.

I want to install Rational Application Developer 8.5, but the launchpad doesn't work.

Hence, I installed the IBM installation Manager and I set the repository:

File -> Preferences -> Repository

I added the repository.config and I restarted the application.

Unfortunately when I start to configure the installation  I get this error:

"Installation Manager non trova i file dei dischi seguenti: 1,2,3,4,5 in IBM® Rational® Application Developer for WebSphere® Software 8.5.1."

Translated:

Installation Manager doesn't find the files of the following disks: 1,2,3,4,5 in IBM® Rational® Application Developer for WebSphere® Software 8.5.1.

I tried to use the master zip as it is suggested here --> https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014848922&ps=25

But this solution was not good for me.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

My RAD software were issue in twelve chunks. I extracted them in order to have a zip file.
I extracted it and I got 5 zip files. I extracted the first four in a folder and the last one in another folder (SETUP).
I used the install.exe inside the SETUP\installation_x86 folder and I went ahead even if I had some warning. When It asked me the first disk I let it point to the folder that I extracted (not the setup, the other one).